# $(document).on for custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using ajax. So to keep form element working after ajax request, it has to use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(document).on("change", "#my-chk", function(){
          $("#my_id input[type=checkbox]").prop('checked', this.checked);
        });

    $(document).on("click", "#add-account", function(){
           $.get('/my_url', function(data){ 
             alert(data);
          });
        });
});
```

However, what should I do to make the following event handler work after ajax request the same way I did above ?

```
$("#my-date-range-picker").daterangepicker(
      {
          ranges: { //.... }
      },
      function(start, end) { //.... }
    );
```

Comment: take care with delegate callbacks, certain events like `change` will not work in all browsers, because the do not bubble up the DOM there.  and this seems to be wrong `$(". input[type=checkbox]")` there a dot with no class name

Comment: it's just typo, don't pay attention to it.

Comment: Why do you need delegated handlers? Can't you simply (re)bind these handlers directly to those elements after the AJAX request is completed? Letting these events bubble all the way up to the `document` is probably more expensive than just handling them directly on the elements.

Comment: you are confusing a plugin with an `event` . `daterangepicker` is not an `event `and needs to be called only when the html exists , within ajax success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you'll have to place a custom event (in this case, `pick-range`) to trigger the creation of your `daterangepicker`. But that's the beauty of event delegation, it's always available regardless of binds

```js
$(document).on('pick-range', '#my-date-range-picker', function(e){
   $(e.currentTarget).daterangepicker(
     {
      ranges: { //.... }
     },
     function(start, end) { //.... }
   );
});

// trigger it
$('#my-date-range-picker').trigger('pick-range');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DZz8R/

Comment: try the fiddle and edit it with your code. and what does `daterangepicker` function uses? binding?

Comment: it don't know. it took it here http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/

Comment: thanks for fiddle but it's going to be quite tough since it's very different from my app.